# How to optimize the Conditional select query that involve inner joins in it?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got an sql query that has lots of INNER JOINS between other tables.

I know that we can use Joins to optimize but as we can see, this query already involved Joins in it. I was thinking to add GROUP BY to this statement which gets more realistic and could run better. Do selecting more columns from one to other tables cause the query slow? If so, how could it work if we need to optimize? Below is my code:

```
SELECT /*PARALLEL(4)*/
    s.task_seq_num,
    s.group_seq_num AS grp_seq_num,
    g.source_type_cd,
    d.doc_id,
    d.doc_ref_id AS doc_ref_id,
    dm.doc_priority_num AS doc_priority,
    s.doc_seq_num AS doc_seq_num,
    s.case_num AS case_num,
    dm.doc_title_name AS doc_title,
    s.task_status_cd AS task_status_cd,
    d.received_dt AS received_dt,
    nvl(b.first_name,d.first_name) AS first_name,
    nvl(b.mid_name,d.mid_name) AS mid_name,
    nvl(b.last_name,d.last_name) AS last_name,
    tg.content_tag_cd AS content_tag_cd,
    d.app_num AS app_num,
    e.head_of_household_sw AS head_of_household_sw,
    f.user_id AS user_id
FROM
    dm_task_status s
    INNER JOIN dm_task_tag tg ON s.task_seq_num = tg.task_seq_num
    INNER JOIN dm_doc_group g ON g.group_seq_num = s.group_seq_num
    INNER JOIN dm_doc d ON d.doc_seq_num = s.doc_seq_num
    INNER JOIN dm_doc_master dm ON dm.doc_ref_id = d.doc_ref_id
    LEFT JOIN mo_employees f ON f.emp_id = s.emp_id
    LEFT JOIN ( dc_case_individual e
    INNER JOIN dc_indv b ON b.indv_id = e.indv_id
                            AND e.head_of_household_sw = 'Y' ) ON e.case_num = s.case_num
WHERE
    s.office_num =38
    AND   s.eff_end_tms IS NULL
    AND   d.delete_sw IS NULL
ORDER BY s.group_seq_num ASC;
```

Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: Is there a specific performance problem you are trying to solve?  Did you look at the explain plan?

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
AND   d.delete_sw IS NULL
```

should be up in the join and not in the WHERE clause. I don't THINK that matters for performance, but don't trust me on that one. But I do know that it's just good policy to only have the final WHERE clause constructed of the primary table itself.

Second, Since we don't know the data itself or the structure of the data, I would say on EACH join, ensure that you're using a table index wherever possible to prevent full table scans. It seems like something that might be insulting to suggest, but I've made the mistake in the past many times without realizing that there was in fact a place where I was NOT using an indexed field to limit the data scanned.

For example, are all of the fields I list below a part of the primary key of their respective tables? If so, are they the FULL primary key? If they are not the full primary key, is there any way that you can get the rest of the primary key values from the table(s) that you're "coming from"? SQL will try to do the best job it can to make the most efficient plan, but it can only go so far, we always have to try to ensure we're using indexed fields and preferably primary keys to ensure that the database doesn't have to work harder than it has to.

Fields in question:

```
dm_task_tag.task_seq_num
dm_doc_group.group_seq_num
dm_doc.doc_seq_num
dm_doc_master.dm.doc_ref_id
mo_employees.emp_id
dc_case_individual.indv_id
dc_case_individual.case_num
```

I'm VERY suspicious of that second LEFT join, but I can't state much about that without knowing the tables. I'm also especially curious if the doc_ref_id is in fact the primary key of the dm_doc_master, or if you have a seq_num that you're missing...

Comment: I really appreciate your patience bennett. Firstly, no difference when i removed d.delete_sw IS NULL  and added into Joins. Secondly,  I am not DBA to access indexes for each table. All the fields mentioned are Primary keys.